# Bibliography not shown

Tags: bibtex, bibliography, overleaf

I can't integrate my bibliography in the document. The error is the bibliography seems to be empty, although I used a citation. I use overleaf.

My minimal code is:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,title page,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=11]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{bib/Meine_Bibliothek.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{GougeonEng}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My bibliography `Meine_Bibliothek.bib` is:

```
@Book{GougeonEng,
  author    = {Meade Gougeon},
  title     = {The Gougeon Brothers on Boat Construction},
  isbn      = {1-878207-50-4},
  publisher = {Gougeon Brothers, Inc.},
  url       = {https://www.westsystem.com/wp-content/uploads/GougeonBook-061205-1.pdf},
  year      = {2005},
}
```

In Addition the citation in the text is underlined. Do you know how I can prevent that?

If I forgot any information to let me know.

I just tried to change a template, added some packages and changed some things and now I can't integrate the bibliography. But in the template it is showing up. It seems like my code is the same as others, but still not working.

Comment: how about using ready templates and interact with them https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates

Comment: Seems to work fine https://www.overleaf.com/read/pkshxzpbxqfs please confirm that you can reproduce the error with your minimal code and also show your .log file